# Laravel 5 - Kodeine ACL using custom resource method inside route protection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, acl, laravel-routing

I'm a newbie to Laravel. I am using Kodeine ACL management for Laravel 5. Generated resourceful controllers and routes. I also added custom method for resourceful controller named "profile"

I am not able to apply ACL if I include custom method if I do this:

```
Route::get('users/profile', UsersController@profile);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'acl'],
          'is' => 'worker',
          'protect_alias' => 'worker.user',
          'protect_methods' => [
                'create' => ['create', 'store'],
                'store'  => ['create', 'store'],
                'read'   => ['index', 'show'],
                'view'   => ['index', 'show'],
                'edit'   => ['edit', 'update', 'profile'],
                'update' => ['edit', 'update', 'profile'],
                'delete' => ['destroy'],
            ]
          ],
function () {
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
});
```

The above code does not applying the ACL to profile method
But if I comment line #1, it applies the ACL, but it is not directing to the profile method [ie $next($request)] doesn't seem to work

Please advise if I am wrong and how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the middle ware files where acl and auth are defined?

Comment: @MwaaJoseph Please find the git source of ACL middleware https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/blob/1.0/src/Kodeine/Acl/Middleware/HasPermission.php